# How to work with CodeIgniter's cookie helper

Tags: codeigniter, cookies, helper

This is my first post in stackoverflow and i'm really excited about that.

Actually i have problems with codeigniter cookie helper.

Take look at my codes:

```
$this->load->helper('cookie');
$cookie = array(
    'name'   => $nid,
    'value'  => 'checked'
);
$this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
echo $this->input->cookie();
// print_r($this->input->cookie();
```

as you see a declared an array called $cookie, then i set the cookie with that. but it seems that i made a mistake in setting cookies, because , the cookie doesn't set !
the immediate calling $this->input->cookie() returns nothing !

Does any one have any suggestion, where do i misunderstand the cookie helper of CI !?

```
var_dump() $this->input->set_cookie($cookie); // This returns NULL !
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give expiration time also in $cookie array and you are not echoing cookie what have you set. try this code

```
       $this->load->helper('cookie');
       $cookie = array(
                       'name'   => $nid,
                       'value'  => 'checked',
                       'expire' => '86500'
                       );
        $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);

        echo $this->input->cookie($nid, TRUE);
```