# Codeigniter Cookie not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies, helper

Not sure why cookies are not working in CI 2.x. Here is my code: 
**Controller:** dashboard.php

```
class Dashboard extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'cookie', 'login'));

        do_login("superuser"); // called the helper function from login helper
        $data['c'] = $this->input->cookie('superuser');
        $this->load->view('dashboard/show', $data);

    }
```

**Helper:** login_helper.php

```
function do_login($cname)
{
    $cookie = array
    (
        'name'   => $cname,
        'value'  => 'The Value',
        'expire' => '86500',
        'domain' => '',
        'path'   => '/',
        'prefix' => 'myprefix_',
        'secure' => TRUE
    );

    get_instance()->input->set_cookie($cookie);
}
```

**View:** show.php

```
<pre>
<?php 
    print_r($c);
?>
</pre>
```

But i can see nothing while i load this page! even there is no cookie was created as shown by EditThisCookie chrome plugin. Am i missing something? Thanks

Comment: Have you loaded cookie helper?

Comment: where, in the helper?

Comment: First of all, check whether you are using cookies helper, if not, include it.

$this->load->helper('cookie');

Comment: review the code in my controller -_-

Comment: Oh i see, my bad, Got it

Comment: You can check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26273771/how-to-work-with-codeigniters-cookie-helper?rq=1